# gfortran localizing a bug that does not occur in the debugger

Tags: windows, fortran, gfortran

I've generated an gfortran executable I call mtc08.exe that exhibits the following behavior:

1)  If I run it in gdb  it runs successfully to the end
2)  If I run it normally, re routing the output with the windows command

```
mtc08.exe >out
```

It gives me "floating point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation" but does not say where that occurs.  (The "backtrace" information is incomprehensible to me, and it seems it cannot contain much information because all is the letter "f".)

Then I'm trying to localize the problem by seeing where the program stops writing results, but having difficulties there also, because I get the impression the program may be multi tasking and proceeding with "future" arithmetic operations before completing output operations that in any case do not interfere.

Does such multi tasking occur?   If so, can I turn it off with a compiler switch, so I'm really sure it is doing all operations sequentially?

The currently used compilation command in windows is:

```
rem debug compilation:
gfortran -static -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-integer-8 -g -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,denormal -Wall -fcheck=all @mtc08.fls -o mtc08.exe
```

where mtc08.fls is a file containing the names of all source files.

It may be that by removing some of the "-ffpe-trap" options it would run, but this rattles my confidence, and I'd like to get to the bottom of it, rather than just find a way around.

I can of course give more information, but seeing the error is not localized, that is not so practical.

Answer (score -1):

I still don't know how to get better diagnostics, but still managed to find the cause of the problem by trial and error, which came from an uninitialized variable.

The problem appears to arise because gdb used zero for uninitialized variables, which should have been their values anyhow, and running the same executable without gdb did use values that lead to "floating point exception".

One way to get better diagnostics in gdb is to use -finit-real-nan in the compilation so that uninitialized variables will get more attention from the debugger.

Perhaps with better coding practice, such as intent declarations for all arguments, the debugger would also be better in picking up uninitialized variables without having to initialize them to nan.